# JSON usage in Python

Tags: python, json, coding-style

I'm looking through the [json documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) and I'm trying to understand how to actually convert a Python object into JSON data, and then convert that data back into a Python object.  I understand you can pass lists, dicts, and tuples of "primitives" like in the example at the top, but I tried creating a very minimal object and passing it to json.dumps() and got "object is not JSON serializable".

What is the proper way to make an object JSON serializable?  I'm currently imagining writing a method which converts my object into a dictionary then passes it to json.dump() and a parallel method to take the dictionary and construct a new object from it.  However that seems really redundant and limited, so I feel like there must be something I'm missing.  Can anyone help fill me in?

Comment: Re: the [best-practice] tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60118/tag-block-request-best-practice

Comment: Aha, I suppose that would be a pretty useless tag in retrospect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `load()` and `dump()`; each [accept an `object_hook` function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/json.html#json.load) to decode and encode objects not ordinarily JSONable. Maybe this will do for you.

Comment: Hmm, I thought `simplejson` was included as `json` in standard Python after 2.6

Comment: @dimo414: you're right. I've edited the reply 15 seconds after writing and realizing this :)

Comment: Thanks.  I found http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/json/ very useful as well, far more so than the Python docs.

Answer (score 0):

The following snipped of code illustrates several aspects of working with JSON in Python 3.  Take note of the JSONEncoder class and the implementation of encoding decimal and datetime.

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal
from datetime import datetime, date

class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, o):
    if isinstance(o, Decimal):
      return float(o)
    elif isinstance(o, (datetime, date)):
      return o.isoformat()
    return super().default(self,o)

class JSONDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
  pass

_Default_Encoder = JSONEncoder(
  skipkeys=False,
  ensure_ascii=False,
  check_circular=True,
  allow_nan=True,
  indent=None,
  separators=None,
  default=None,
  )

_Default_Decoder = JSONDecoder(
  object_hook=None, 
  object_pairs_hook=None
  )

Encode = _Default_Encoder.encode
Decode = _Default_Decoder.decode
```