# Strange behavior parsing JSON dicts into objects using object_hook

Tags: python, json

I have been [exploring the json library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882189/json-usage-in-python), and am attempting to convert an object into JSON data and back again.  I have run into trouble running this example code:

```
import json

class Obj:
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(self,s,hello="Hello world!"):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.s = s
        self.hello = hello
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MyObj(%s,%s)>' % (self.s, self.hello)

def objToJSON(obj):
    return obj.__dict__

def jSONToObj(json):
    print(json)
    return Obj(**json)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    str = json.dumps(Obj("Hello","World"), default=objToJSON, sort_keys=True)
    print(str)
    print(json.loads(str,object_hook=jSONToObj))
    str = json.dumps(Obj("Text",{"a":"aaaa","b":"BBBBB","C":"ccccc"}), default=objToJSON, sort_keys=True)
    print(str)
    print(json.loads(str,object_hook=jSONToObj))
```

The output of which is:

```
{"hello": "World", "s": "Hello"}
{'s': 'Hello', 'hello': 'World'}
<MyObj(Hello,World)>
{"hello": {"C": "ccccc", "a": "aaaa", "b": "BBBBB"}, "s": "Text"}
{'a': 'aaaa', 'C': 'ccccc', 'b': 'BBBBB'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dimo414\src\test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(json.loads(str,object_hook=jSONToObj))
  File "C:\Python31\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python31\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
  File "C:\Users\dimo414\src\test.py", line 22, in jSONToObj
    return Obj(**json)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

It seems that when a dictionary is a value in the object's dictionary, the data passed to jSONToObj is the internal dictionary, not the full dictionary.  Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you specified that objects should be reconstructed using the function `jSONToObj`, the deserializer assumes that all dicts are to be objects and tries to call your deserializer on them.

From the docs:

> `object_hook` is an optional function
>   that will be called with the result of
>   any object literal decode (a dict).
>   The return value of object_hook will
>   be used instead of the dict. This
>   feature can be used to implement
>   custom decoders (e.g. JSON-RPC class
>   hinting).

The inner dict is the first to be deserialized, probably because `loads` works recursively and starts from the bottom layer. It makes sense that before deserializing an object, you have to deserialize its arguments.

Comment: Why does the deserializer assume all dicts are objects?  why cant an object contain a dict?

Comment: Because the dicts do not have type annotations by themselves, so the json function can never tell. Your deserializer function `jSONToObj` has to decide for itself what is a dict and what is not a dict, and return either an object or a dict, as is appropriate.

Comment: By the way, if you only want top-level objects, consider deserializing the data from JSON as usual and then manually converting the resulting dict/list to objects.

Comment: Yes, I realized that I was misunderstanding the purpose of the object_hook parameter.  Thanks for your help!